# Provide an option to hide the list of tags in the custom filters display

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

Can we have an option to hide the list of tags in the **Edit profile and settings -> Preferences**.

When I have huge number of tags in the filters, it is occupied some part of the screen, Also I don't want to see those tags all the time.

So based on user's need, shall we enable or disable those list of tags?

Currently how it is looking:

[image: Current]

Expected behaviour:

[image: Expect]

Comment: Also requested on MSO: [Ability to collapse "Tagged with" tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387391/6296561)